# How can I have builds fail if new code is below coverage threshold?

Tags: java, unit-tests, code-coverage

Is there any Java testing framework (preferably Jacoco and/or Sonar) that will allow teams with poor code coverage, to forgive the existing code base, but require new code to be above a threshold, (until they can get all of the old code covered!)